# Detecting a mouse click / mouse up in NetLogo

Tags: user-interface, mouse, netlogo

Using `mouse-down?` for mouse actions in NetLogo often results in the action happening too many times. For example, if you want to let users click to create new turtles, you could hook a forever button up to a procedure like:

```
to add-turtle
  if mouse-down? [
    crt 1 [ setxy mouse-xcor mouse-ycor ]
  ]
end
```

The problem is that this usually results in many turtles being created per click. I'd like to do something like:

```
to add-turtle
  if mouse-clicked? [
    crt 1 [ setxy mouse-xcor mouse-ycor ]
  ]
end
```

Where `mouse-clicked?` is true right as the person clicks (right after they left up the mouse button).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you do have to keep track of it yourself, but the good news is that its not hard.

The key is to create a global called `mouse-was-down?` that is set to true if `mouse-down?` was true in the last time your mouse-oriented procedure was called. Then `mouse-clicked?` can be defined as follows:

```
to-report mouse-clicked?
  report (mouse-was-down? = true and not mouse-down?)
end
```

It seems to work well in conjunction with a central mouse-management procedure that calls the other click-based procedures. For example:

```
globals [ mouse-was-down? ]

to-report mouse-clicked?
  report (mouse-was-down? = true and not mouse-down?)
end

to mouse-manager
  let mouse-is-down? mouse-down?
  if mouse-clicked? [
    add-turtle
    ; Other procedures that should be run on mouse-click
  ]
  set mouse-was-down? mouse-is-down?
end

to add-turtle
  crt 1 [ setxy mouse-xcor mouse-ycor ]
end
```

Using the `mouse-is-down?` local variable keeps the behavior more consistent if the mouse button is released before `mouse-manager` finishes.

Comment: See also e.g. Mouse Drag One Example, in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library. It uses a `while [mouse-down?] ...` style loop.

Answer (score 2):

Hello probably this is a bit late for your purpose, but in case anyone has the same problem, this is how I solved this in my models for now.

```
to add-turtle
  if mouse-down? [
    crt 1 [ setxy mouse-xcor mouse-ycor ]
    stop
  ]
end
```

The workaround here is to add a "stop" command to kill the "create-new-turtle" forever button. The only tradeoff is that you will have to press again to create another new turtle.

Answer (score 0):

Bryan Head's answer didn't work for me, it still created multiple turtles in one click.

Alternative:
A (non-forever) button which does `crt 1 [ setxy mouse-xcor mouse-ycor ]` 
with action key `A`.
Now all you need to do to add a turtle is press or hold `A` with your left hand while mousing with your right hand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to Bryan's code, in case you want to perform an action as soon as the mouse button is clicked (instead of waiting until it's released):

```
globals [ mouse-clicked? ]

to mouse-manager
  ifelse mouse-down? [
    if not mouse-clicked? [
      set mouse-clicked? true
      crt 1 [ setxy mouse-xcor mouse-ycor ]
    ]
  ] [
    set mouse-clicked? false
  ]
end
```

Comment: The only caveat is that you have to make sure _not_ to assign a keyboard shortcut to your "forever" button. That's to avoid a click being registered in the view before the `mouse-clicked?` variable has a chance to get initialized to a boolean (instead of the default value `0`). The alternative would be to write `if mouse-clicked != true` instead of `not mouse-clicked?`, but that's not as readable).