# How do you mouseclick to kill a turtle in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

im trying to make a whack a mole game for netlogo
any help would be appreciated
here is my full length code

```
globals [
  game-over?
```

]

```
To setup
 ca
 set game-over? false
 ask patches [set pcolor green]
end

To play
 if game-over? [
  ask turtles [die]
  ask patch 0 4 [set plabel "GAME OVER"]
 ] 
set-default-shape turtles "ant 2"
crt 1
ask turtle 0 [
set size 7
set color brown
set xcor random 33 - 16
set ycor random 33 - 16]
if mouse-down? [
 ask turtles with [round xcor = round mouse-xcor and round ycor = round mouse-ycor] [
 die]
]

end
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22134822/detecting-a-mouse-click-mouse-up-in-netlogo ?

Comment: i know what mouse-down does, but im having trouble making it work when i click to kill a turtle

Comment: Your previous version of this question, that showed the code you wrote that didn't quite work, was better. The code you provided was almost right. Why not show it to us again, so we can help you fix it?

Comment: forgot to include my code, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. But a turtle's `xcor` will hardly ever exactly equal `round mouse-xcor`, unless the turtle happens to be standing on a patch center. If your turtles aren't dying, that's probably why.

Adding some more rounding should make it work:

```
if mouse-down? [
  ask turtles with [round xcor = round mouse-xcor and round ycor = round mouse-ycor] [
    die
  ]
]
```

But note that it's actually easier to take advantage of the patch grid than to use `round`. The following code does the same thing without explicit rounding:

```
if mouse-down? [
  ask turtles-on patch mouse-xcor mouse-ycor [
    die
  ]
]
```

Depending on how you want your game to work, you might also consider ignoring the patch boundaries as a basis for determining what turtle was clicked, and just compute the actual distance of the turtle from the click point:

```
if mouse-down? [
  ask turtles with [distancexy mouse-xcor mouse-ycor < 0.5] [
    die
  ]
]
```

The `0.5` here is arbitrary; you could adjust it up or down to control the sensitivity.

Comment: i see why your code makes sense, and it should seem to work, yet none of them work

Comment: there's my full code so far, is anything maybe wrong with the rest of it, causing the mouseclick not to work?

Comment: I would suggest adding print statements to the code to improve your understanding of what's going on. That'll show you what parts of your code are being run and what parts aren't. You can print the values of expressions of interest, like `round mouse-xcor` and `round mouse-ycor`, to see what their values are. Also you are running `play` inside a forever button, right?

Comment: Here is a complete working .nlogo file showing that the code works: http://cl.ly/3T0T1L202E1I/Whack%20a%20Turtle.nlogo

Comment: AHHHH, my problem was the go button... i forgot it wasnt forever. Thanks, appreciate your help